# JLabel specific GIF animation plays too fast

Tags: java, swing, animation, jlabel, animated-gif

This specific GIF animation plays too fast, like 100x the normal speed. Is there any fix to this? or should I just slow the "normal speed of the GIF further"?

```
public class Test {

    private static final String url = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnrWw.gif";

    private void display() throws MalformedURLException {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new URL(url))));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new Test().display();
                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What;s the relevant code?

Comment: @AliAlamiri updated it

Comment: I would suggest that the expected delay value for each from is missing.  Do you have a GIF editor?

Comment: @MadProgrammer the GIF wasn't made by me? should i ask her to fix it

Comment: @vincentbelkin It's difficult to tell.  I loaded another Gif and it worked fine, so I can only guess that the gif you have isn't encoded correctly for Java

Comment: @MadProgrammer You could always try loading via the the default toolkit. It will handle animated gifs.

Comment: @Nikki `ImageIcon` uses `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(filename)`

Comment: @MadProgrammer It does? I learn something new everyday.

Comment: Don't use `setBounds()` to position the label (and button). Let a layout manager do its job. Then it will still work even if the image is changed in the future.

Comment: true, agreed part of animated gif have got crazy repainting in Java, I'm never solved that but there must be solution(s) for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using an other animated gif image which works just fine, the problem is probably your gif image, try slowing down the frame rate of your gif or lowering the quality.